# Adding a do-while in a simple RPG game issue

Tags: java

I'm building a simple RPG game. I'm stuck with a problem that might be solved with a do-while loop, I think. The method down below shows the way a player buys an item, but currently, they can only buy one item. I want to add an option to buy multiple items, instead of just one. There's a knife, a sword, etc., and I want to give a player an option to buy more than one (a sword and a potion, for example).

As I said, I guess I could do it with a do-while loop, but I'm not sure how to implement it. Would it be even better to make a second method just with a do-while loop? And to call it from the buyItems() method to keep the code a bit more readable?

```
public static void buyItems() {

        player.displayPocketCoins();

        System.out.println("Buy an item: \n" +
                "- Press 1 for buying a knife. The cost is 5 coins.\n" +
                "- Press 2 for buying a sword. The cost is 10 coins.\n" +
                "- Press 3 for buying a spear. The cost is 15 coins.\n" +
                "- Press 4 for buying a potion. The cost is 30 coins.");
        int choice = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                if(player.getCoins() >= 5) {
                player.addToInventory(shopping.availableItems.get(0));
                player.coinSpent(5);
                System.out.println("you bought a knife.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You don't have enough coins.");
                    buyItems();
            }
                break;
            case 2:
                if(player.getCoins() >= 10) {
                    player.addToInventory(shopping.availableItems.get(1));
                    player.coinSpent(10);
                    System.out.println("you bought a sword.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You don't have enough coins.");
                    buyItems();
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if(player.getCoins() >= 15) {
                    player.addToInventory(shopping.availableItems.get(2));
                    player.coinSpent(15);
                    System.out.println("you bought a spear.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You don't have enough coins.");
                    buyItems();
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if(player.getCoins() >= 30) {
                    player.addToInventory(shopping.availableItems.get(3));
                    player.coinSpent(30);
                    System.out.println("you bought a potion.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You don't have enough coins.");
                    buyItems();
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid number, please try again.");
                break;
        }
            player.displayRemainingCoins();
    }
```

Comment: Add a do while and add the option to quit the shop.

Comment: Well, you could do it with any kind of loop, just try it. As for the second method: that would probably not help here but again: try it and see how it "feels".

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. The problem is, I don't know where to insert a do-while. Should the entire switch be inside the loop?

Comment: yes the switch should then be in the loop and an option to quit it of course.

Comment: I put the entire switch inside the while loop, it works now as it should. Thank you for your help!